# Report in .rdlc format exported to PDF as read only C#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, rdlc

I'm working in an app in .NET where i'm using a report (.rdlc format) that i export to PDF. My client needs the PDF to be read only for security purposes. I already tried with FileAttributes and FileInfo libraries.

My biggest problem is that when i see my PDF properties, the checkbox for read-only is ticked but then i try to edit the fields with Adobe Acrobat and i am able to do it.

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean ? You don't export an rdlc report (or any report). You *render* it and ouput the results in a PDF file. The file's attributes have nothing to do with the PDF file itself - the read-only attribute means that you can't modify the file unless you remove it, something very easy to do. Making the PDF itself protected is another matter. I doubt that VS 2010 had that functionality.

Comment: You're right, i'm not exporting it but rendering it. After this, i'm saving what was rendered in my file system as PDF. Then, if i open the file with Adobe Acrobat there is a tool "TouchUp" that allows the user to edit the text boxes in the file. This is what i wanted to prevent. Do you know any way of not letting this happen through coding? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by importing iTextSharp library and using the following code:

[image]

I couldn't solve my problem without rendering and saving the PDF first in the file system as a dummy file, i.e., with all permissions. As you can see in the code, afterwards, i refer to the same dummy file and change it's permissions with static method Encrypt() from the iTextSharp library. Then, i save my finished and restricted PDF to the file system and delete the dummy one.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need create PDF/A files. It is separate archive standard of PDF (not "readonly" property). So when you open PDF/A files you get notification that it is archive file. End-user could edit any file, but in such case "archive" property will lost.
Unfortunately SSRS could not make PDF/A files.

Comment: Hello Merl. Thank you for your reply. I already solved this issue. Gonna publish the answer.

Answer (score 0):

May be, you should look for another report generator. Something like Crystal or FastReport. I checked FR and ensured that it can create PDF/A.

Comment: Hello xaml. I gave the answer to this problem right now. Feel free to give it a look. I used Crystal Reports before the "normal" report solution (.rdlc format) but i couldn't export to PDF with a page size below A4. That's the reason why i used .rdlc format.